# No file %.nls while using nomencl

Tags: texworks, nomenclature

I would like to use nomencl. I have the following code:

```
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\nomenlature{test}{This is a test}
\printnomenclature
\makeindex My_file.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o My_file.nls"
```

I receive the following error:

> No file My_file.nls.

All my files are in the same folder and I can see the nlo file.

I am using TeXworks (pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX) and Windows Vista.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `\makeindex` doesn't have any arguments. The arguments you are showing must be used for the compilation `makeindex`:

Suppose your file has the name `demo` than you have to call

```
pdfLaTeX demo.tex
makeindex demo.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o demo.nls
bibtex demo.aux
pdfLaTeX demo.tex
pdfLaTeX demo.tex
```

---

To test the compilation steps you can use the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\nomenclature{test}{This is a test}

\begin{document}
\section{foo}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

### [image]

You can simplify the compilation by using arara:

Add the lines to your header:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex
```

and compile the file with `arara`. The documentation describes the integration of `arara` inside TeXWorks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same error. I will try arara now...

Comment: @Denis: Please see my edit. Does the example fail for you?

Comment: Could you show me the full tex script you are using? Including commands...

Comment: @Denis: what do you mean? The example is saved as `demo.tex` and the compilation is shown too.

Comment: Where do I put the makeindex, pdflatex etc lines? Before or after the documentclass. I always receive the message that \begin{document} is missing

Comment: @Denis: These lines don't contain to the tex-file. These are compilation steps which are done in the terminal.